# Gmail api for attachment not working in anuglar 9

Tags: angular, gmail, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail api in Angular 9. After authentication, when I send an email for the first time its not sending the email. Once I refresh the page, only then does the email send correctly. If I send with an attachment I am getting the message and base64 content. How can I fix this issue?

I am going to attach pdf,jpg,txt,gif files i have updated my code snippet.

**My code snippet:**

```js
const message = [
          'MIME-Version: 1.0',
         "From:" + this.useremail +"\r\n" +
           "To: " + to +"\r\n" + gmailcc +
           "Subject:" + subject +"\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\n\n"+sendMessage+"",
           'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary='+foo_bar_baz+'\r\n',
           '--'+foo_bar_baz+'\r\n',
          'Content-Type: image/png\r\n',        
          'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n',
          'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='+filename+'\n\n\n',
          localUrl.slice(localUrl.indexOf(',') + 1), '\n\n\n',
          '--'+foo_bar_baz+'--'
         ].join("");
         
        gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
            gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', () => {
            gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken') });
            gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
              userId: this.useremail,  
              uploadType:'multipart',      
              resource: {
                raw:btoa(message).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_'),
              }
            }).then(res => {          
              var returnbody=JSON.parse(res.body);  
              
              
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you also share the code sample that triggers this function (a button, form submit, etc) as I think the first issue might be related to the logic behind it? Also, what type of files are you trying to send? Depending on this you should user [Simple upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple), [Multipart upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart) or a [Resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable).

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply. i have updated my code snippet.

Comment: Hi !I was referring to the ```component.html``` part that triggered sending this message. Also, for multipart upload you must present your data in a base64 encoded string as described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments#resource:-messagepartbody) and pass it in the body of the request as reflected [in this example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#example:-multipart-upload). What would be the approximate file size you would be sending? Depending on that you might not want to be using multipart upload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. Could you please post as an answer to this question what solved your issue so that other users with similar problems can easily find it? Thanks ! :D

Comment: I have changed the concatenation method to send the attachment

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the concatination method to fix the issue

var message = '';
message =
'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n'+
"To: " + to + "\r\n" + gmailcc +
"Subject: " + subject +"\r\n\r\n";

```
     message += "--foo_bar_baz\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/html;charset='UTF-8'\r\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
        message += "\r\n" + sendMessage+"\r\n\r\n";
 
        message += "--foo_bar_baz\r\n" +
     "Content-Type: application/pdf;attachment;filename="+uploafiles+"\r\n" +
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
     "Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="+uploafiles+"\r\n\r\n" +
     localUrl.slice(localUrl.indexOf(',') + 1)+ "\r\n\r\n";


 gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
  gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', () => {
  gapi.client.setToken({ access_token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken') });
  gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: this.useremail,  
    uploadType:'multipart',      
    resource: {
      raw:btoa(message).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_'),
    }
  }).then(res => {          
    var returnbody=JSON.parse(res.body);  
  });
});
```

});